# Select and add records separating by month and year in report

Tags: mysql, laravel, charts

I am using LaraCharts and I need to select in a report the sum total related to that month and year in the records.

```
$value = DB::table('values')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'value.id_loja')
        ->join('clients', 'clients.id', '=', 'value.id_cliente')
        ->GROUPBY (YEAR(`due_date`),MONTH(`due_date`))
        ->get();
        $total_value = $value->sum('cust');
```

This example I used groupby. and it's returning me error.

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\YEAR()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DB::raw() to use mysql functions

```
->GROUPBY (DB::raw('YEAR(due_date)'), DB::raw('MONTH(price)')
```

More here:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions